# how to jquery .load() from web-inf folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, load, directory

How would the url look if I'm trying to .load() a file in WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/jsp2.jsp from a file in WebContent/js/jsFile.js

I've tried

> "../WEB-INF/jsp/file.jsp"
>
> "/WEB-INF/jsp/file.jsp"
>
> "WEB-INF/jsp/file.jsp"
>
> "/jsp/file.jsp"
>
> "jsp/file.jsp"

**Edit:**

```
    $("#Submit").live({
        click: function(){
            $("#listView").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            });
            $("#screenView").load({
                url: "../WEB-INF/jsp/jspFile2.jsp",
                complete: function(){
                    alert("completed");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the code I'm using to load from WEB-INF/jsp/jspFile1.jsp.. It's not rendering the jspFile2.jsp in the screenView div as I was expecting..

the div screenView and listView are siblings.

Thanks,

wenn

Comment: Is the WEB-INF-directory accessible through HTTP?

Comment: the WEB-INF folder should NOT be accessible via http! Password files and the like maybe stored in there. Tomcat will not deliver anything from there, at least in the default config.

Comment: You JSPs should not be placed inside the WEB-INF dir.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, It's not accessible.

Comment: see Tim's comment, load will request via HTTP, if it is not accessible via HTTP you'll need to move the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first one you wrote is correct:

```
 "../WEB-INF/jsp/file.jsp"
```

if you post more info about the error and your code we could provide a more detailed answer (maybe the problem is different from what you think)

Answer (score 0):

../WEB-INF/jsp/file.jsp  is correct, you must be having another problem.  try redirecting the browser to the file and see if it shows up.