# Redirect to jsp file in WEB-INF using Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm using ajax to submit login form details in my web app. If username and password are correct, i need to redirect user to `home.jsp` page in `web-inf` folder.

I have tried with requestdispatcher and it not worked.

Also tried as `json.put("url", "/WEB-INF/home.jsp");` in my servlet and `window.location = json.url;` in javascript and it also not worked.

**My Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user-login-form').submit(function() {

        var postdata = $('#user-login-form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {

              if(json.errorMessage != '') {
                      alert(json.errorMessage);
              }else{
                  // redirect to jsp file in web-inf
              }                 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Part of my Servlet code**

```
if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("pass")) {

    // in here, i need to redirect user to home.jsp page in web-inf folder

} else {
    json.put("errorMessage", "Invalid username or password");
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847038/how-to-jquery-load-from-web-inf-folder

Comment: you can try `<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/home.jsp"/>` or `<jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/home.jsp"/>` in JSP but it will not change the URL and the response of home.jsp is included in the current JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect user to only publicly available resources,

anything inside WEB-INF isn't publicly accessible , you might want to redirect user to a servlet from where you can forward request to your home.jsp inside WEB-INF

Comment: Was about to add this to my comment. It's probably best handling redirects from the server side. The only time when this is not an option is when you're trying to make your page completely AJAX based, and it is obvious that OP is not. +1

Comment: Thank you. now my problem is solved. but have a little question. I have redirect user to a servlet and from there redirect user to `/WEB-INF/home.jsp` using `RequestDispatcher`. now url show as `http://localhost:8181/TCD/redirect`. Is there any way to show `home.jsp` instead of `redirect` in url ?

Comment: use `response.sendRedirect()`. `RequestDispatcher` is used for forward and include the that append the HTML content in the same request.